# wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: http, go, winsock

When sending Post to a https rest api endpoint in my local network I'm receiving the error:

```
wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

However, when I use Postman on the same server it works fine.

The problem is specific to my Go http configuration, I'm just not sure what the problem is.

I've tried disabling TLS on the http client but the problem persists:

```
// disable SSLVerify
func getHttpClient() *http.Client {
    tr := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}} // disable SSL integrity check
    return &http.Client{Transport: tr}
}
```

edit: correction, it's being routed over a proxy, probably Bluecoat, that's performing some MitM operations. But still can't figure out why it works over Postman, but not with Golang.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I'm receiving an error" part? Please post a minimal piece of your real code which performs the request and the exact statement which fails with this error.

Comment: Another question: can you somehow verify what happens on the remote end when you perform your request? The error looks suspiciously like the remote end does not understand the request and crashes or tears the _connection_ down. This—it it actually happens—might be accompanied by a certain logging pattern or something like this.

Comment: I'm suspicious because the error mentions `wsarecv` which, on Windows™, is a function which reads from a _connected_ socket which means connection supposedly went OK when the request started (or existed, in case it was pooled).

Comment: More googling for the exact error message text (a usual tactic in such cases) turns up suspiciously large number of problems occuring due to the remote end expecting SSL/TLS while the local one is not using it (for an example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800987/720999) and [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3785)). Can you verify you're not using `https://` in your request URL when connecting to a port which does not expect TLS—or vice-versa?

Comment: The logic behing the latter hypothesis is like follow: the connecting phase (I mean TCP handshake) goes well—as on that phase it's not known what protocol will be transported over the socket)—and then when the clent sends plain text to the remote end which expects the TLS handshake traffic, the remote end considers the ingress traffic to be gibberish and bails out, terminating the connection. The reverse could also be true—producing much the same outcome.

Comment: @kostix It seems to be related to the Bluecoat Proxy that's doing a man in the middle on the ssl proxy.  I'll update the question.

Comment: So you're using HTTPS in both cases, right? Then a plausible hypothesis is that Bluecoat somehow gets screwed while talking to your Go program. I'd use tcpdump and/or Wireshark to capture the failing exchange and look for clues in the traffic dump.